# String appending function doesn't work

Tags: c, string, memory-management

I tried to create a function that easily appends two strings. The source string has to be previously allocated dynamically. I used my knowledge but this resulted in ub and any sort of leaks.

---

```
void strapp (char *source_offset, int position, char *appendage)
{
    size_t appendage_size = strlen(appendage);

    source_offset = realloc(source_offset, strlen(source_offset) + appendage_size);
    sprintf( &source_offset[position], "%s%s", appendage, source_offset + (position + appendage_size) );
}
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just use the good old `strcat`?

Comment: Because this is a function I created for an engine. This is not a coding from scratch.. and `strcat` isn't included because of a mysterious reason.

Comment: How is the caller supposed to know where did his string go if `realloc` decides to move it elsewhere? Also, you fell into the usual `x = realloc(x, n)` antipattern.

Comment: You mean.. I have to return the new area as a `char*` or something? Also what do you mean by antipattern?

Comment: @AlanSalios you should *seriously* consider Matteo's comment above, and either pass `source_offset` by address (a pointer-to-pointer) or utilize the currently unused result of this function.

Comment: What is `position` supposed to be?  Regardless of what it is, the `sprintf` args seem non-sensical -- what are they trying to do?

Comment: To the place where the caller wants to add a substring, it adds the substring and the rest of the source string after it.

Comment: And if `position` is beyond the current length of the passed `source_offset` ? Then what? Fyi, a series of several sample sources, append strings, positions, and the *expected* results posted in your question would make this *considerably* clearer.

Comment: Your `realloc` needs to take into account `position` so it obviously is allocating the wrong number of bytes; and also you cannot use overlapping buffers for both the input and output of `sprintf` (causes undefined behaviour to try). And you never return the result of `realloc` so the calling code will cause undefined behaviour when it tries to access the old buffer.

Comment: If you post some examples of input and the corresponding expected output then someone will be able to show correct code

Comment: So many problems I see..

Comment: ... and so few samples with inputs and expected outputs we see.

Comment: @MatteoItalia `x = realloc(x, n);` is fine so long as you plan to abort the process on failure.  The pass-by-value error is orthogonal  (it'd still occur if using the better realloc pattern)

Comment: @Matt: 1) in that case, I prefer to have a separate function that calls `abort()` in case of failure to make this explicit. 2) I never said that they aren't orthogonal (actually, the `realloc` antipattern thing is mostly an afterthought, I noticed it tangentially while commenting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source_offset + (position + appendage_size)` is somehow strange. It seems that you tried to catenate the second string with a substring of the first copying the result in the first string.

`source_offset + (position + appendage_size)` is the suffix of the source string starting at offset `position+appendage_size` which is a non-sense as it is past the end of the source string...

May be you wanted something like this?
If you want to catenate the two string then the following is correct:

```
size_t appendage_size = strlen(appendage);
source_offset = realloc(source_offset, position + appendage_size + 1);
sprintf( &source_offset[position], "%s", appendage );
```

Which appends `appendage` to `source_offset` starting at `position`.

Now if you want to insert `appendage` in the middle this can be a little more tricky:

```
size_t appendage_size = strlen(appendage);
char *result = malloc(strlen(source_offset) + appendage_size + 1);
char cut = source_offset[position];
source_offset[position] = '\0';
sprintf( result, "%s%s%c%s", source_offset,appendage,cut,source_offset+position+1);
// do hat you want with result
```

Beware that `realloc` may change the base address of the initial memory, so you can't do things like this as the parameter value `source_offset` will be changed only locally.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t appendage_size = strlen(appendage) + 1; /* To hold a \0 character */
```

The new array allocated should be able to hold both the null characters in each string

`strlen(string) + 1`

Comment: It still doesn't work. Usage: `char *str1 = malloc(11 + 1);

strcpy(str1, "Hello World");

strapp(str1, 4, " Horrible ");

printf(str1);
free(str1);`

Comment: @AlanSalios In order to append you need to realloc() to hold the new string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix your function try this:

```
void strapp (char **source_offset, int position, char *appendage)
{
    size_t appendage_size = strlen(appendage);

    *source_offset = (char*)realloc(*source_offset, strlen(*source_offset) + appendage_size);
    sprintf( *source_offset + position, "%s%s", appendage, *source_offset + (position + appendage_size) );
}
```

And call this like `strapp(&str, 10, "INSERTION"); // &str - pointer to pointer`.

The problem was in the following: when you sent pointer to function you are able to change data pointed by this pointer, but cannot change the pointer, so memory allocation made inside function do mot change address of initial string.

Comment: Like that it doesn't print out what is after the appended substring. At least it isn't a leak like it was before..

Answer (score 0):

actually your coes does not append string B to string A, it does append string B at position n of string A along with string A, with some out of memory offset of String A

```
char *
strapp(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    size_t i,j;
    for (i = 0; dest[i] != '\0'; i++)
        ;
    for (j = 0; src[j] != '\0'; j++)
        dest[i+j] = src[j];
    dest[i+j] = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

the above code appends string B to String A and returns pointer to string a A;

```
char* strapp (char *source_offset, const char *appendage, int position)
{
    char* temp = NULL:
    size_t appendage_size = strlen(appendage);
    if (( temp = realloc(source_offset, strlen(source_offset) + appendage_size + 1)) == NULL )
        return NULL;
    else
        source_offset = temp;
    sprintf( &source_offset[position], "%s", appendage);
    return source_offset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I was asked to provide an example of function usage and respectively the output. I converted this code to something compilable to mingw and it works like expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void strapp (char *source_offset, int position, char *appendage)
{
    size_t appendage_size = strlen(appendage) + 1;

    source_offset = realloc(source_offset, strlen(source_offset) + appendage_size);
    sprintf( &source_offset[position], "%s%s", appendage, source_offset + (position + appendage_size) );
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str1 = malloc(11 + 1);

    sprintf(str1, "Hello World");

    strapp(str1, 4, " Horrible ");

    printf(str1);
    free(str1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: `Hell Horrible`

Comment: Since when `malloc` has two arguments?

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure you can correct it by yourself, albeit I made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Partial fix of the problem I found while investigating.
If I add a substring to a location of the source string like that:

`sprintf(&source[4], "new");`

the source string will be terminated by the `"new"` and the rest of the string will not be shown.
But if I declare the substring `"new"` and use
`memcpy(&str1[4], appendage, 3);` it does the job.

---

There, this is the working function:

```
void strapp (char *source_offset, int position, char *appendage)
{
    size_t appendage_size = strlen(appendage) + 1;
    char copy[strlen(source_offset) + 1];

    strcpy(copy, source_offset);

    source_offset = realloc(source_offset, strlen(source_offset) + appendage_size);
    memcpy(&source_offset[position], appendage, strlen(appendage));
    sprintf(&source_offset[position + strlen(appendage)], &copy[position]);
}
```